# Deserializing JSON to a list of a custom class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I have some JSON I am trying to deserialize (https://api.zype.com/consumers/?api_key=qfcR4WWqBws1ezeUHNxTTQl8ucuuP9pW1rMssmQBFUE-AbpPhKp_cY0RnfpY57y5):

I have a Consumer class and ZypeConsumerList:

```
Public Class Consumer
    <JsonProperty("email")>
    Public Property Email As String
    <JsonProperty("stripe_id")>
    Public Property StripeId As List(Of String)
    <JsonProperty("_id")>
    Public Property Id As String
    <JsonProperty("_keywords")>
    Public Property Keywords As List(Of String)
    <JsonProperty("created_at")>
    Public Property CreatedOn As Nullable(Of Date)
    <JsonProperty("updated_at")>
    Public Property UpdatedOn As Nullable(Of Date)
    <JsonProperty("deleted_at")>
    Public Property DeletedOn As Nullable(Of Date)
    <JsonProperty("site_id")>
    Public Property SiteId As String
    <JsonProperty("subscription_count")>
    Public Property SubscriptionCount As Int16
End Class

Public Class ZypeConsumerList
    <JsonProperty("response")>
    Public Property Consumers As List(Of DanceNetwork.Zype.Consumer)
    <JsonProperty("pagination")>
    Public Property Pagination As DanceNetwork.Zype.Pagination
End Class
```

I'm trying to deserialize the JSON:

```
        Dim zResponse As ZypeResponse = myCall.Execute(ZypeRestEndpoint.Consumers)
        Dim responseBlock As ZypeConsumerList
        Dim mySerializerSettings As JsonSerializerSettings = New JsonSerializerSettings()
        mySerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        responseBlock = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ZypeConsumerList)(zResponse.data, mySerializerSettings)
```

I get this error:

```
 Error converting value "cus_AHtHxKXCwe6MPZ" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. Path 'response[3].stripe_id', line 1, position 2043.
```

I don't see anywhere the JSON is malformed and the above value is in fact a string. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Isn't stipe_id a string? You have it defined as a List(Of String) in your class.

Comment: Why do you have this tagged as C# when your code is VB?

Comment: I don't know how you created those classes, but what i usually do, is go to http://json2csharp.com/ to generate the class based on the json result, to avoid any error like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure works for me

```
public class Consumer
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string amazon_user_id { get; set; }
    public string birthday { get; set; }
    public string braintree_id { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string pass_count { get; set; }
    public string password_token { get; set; }
    public string playlist_count { get; set; }
    public string remember_token { get; set; }
    public string rss_token { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public string site_id { get; set; }
    public string stripe_id { get; set; }
    public string subscription_count { get; set; }
    public string terms { get; set; }
    public string transaction_count { get; set; }
    public string updates { get; set; }
    public string video_count { get; set; }
    public List<string> linked_devices { get; set; }
}

public class Pagination
{
    public string current { get; set; }
    public string previous { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
    public string per_page { get; set; }
    public string pages { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the code to access the elements

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new StreamReader("sample.json"))
        {

            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(stream.ReadToEnd());
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var responses in rootObject.response)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(responses.stripe_id);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(rootObject.pagination.current);
            Console.WriteLine(rootObject.pagination.next);
            Console.WriteLine(rootObject.pagination.pages);
            Console.WriteLine(rootObject.pagination.per_page);
            Console.WriteLine(rootObject.pagination.previous);


        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

**Update** I am using c# code because your tag is C#.